# Facebook feed Dialog implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I need to develop a functionality in my IOS app, where I wish to post/publish a url. When the same url is pasted in the Facebook website's update status textbox, it generates a beautiful thumbnail and Description of the item. I think that this is the feed generated by the Facebook. I tried and searched for several tutorials which help me in developing the dialog in my iOS, but they are not helpful. I even went through facebook's ios developers website, but I was unable to understand/implement anything. The basic problems I face are

1. Unable to include FBDialog which is in deprecated headers, but available under FacebookSDKResources.bundle.
2. Unable to find FBWebDialog anywhere
3. All the tutorials I found are for previous version of the Facebook SDK.

Also please direct me towards any tutorial which will help me in completing my project. It will be really helpful if someone can point me towards a tutorial with source code available explaning the FBDialog's functionality